# I keep getting a error on the oauth with Python3 sdk : self.token = access_token_dict['oauth_token'] KeyError: 'oauth_token'

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, evernote

I just got my key activated for evernote and I am struggling with the oauth.

When requesting oauths tokens via this method:
`request_token = client.get_request_token('http://localhost')`

I get my 3 arguments:

- oauth_token
- oauth_token_secret
- oauth_callback_confirmed

Then trying to get my access token using this method:

```
access_token = client.get_access_token(
     oauth_token = request_token['oauth_token'] ,
     oauth_token_secret= request_token['oauth_token_secret'],
     oauth_verifier=oauth_verifier )
```

I don't understand where I get the `oauth_verifier` from. I used 2222 as it's what everyone seems to use,
but I still get that error:

```
line 69, in get_access_token
     self.token = access_token_dict['oauth_token'] KeyError: 'oauth_token'`
```

Trying to get an access token and tried to pass arguments manually.

Answer (score 0):

`oauth_token` is not in the `request_token`,  this means `client.get_request_token('http://localhost')` did not get correct result. Checking your api_key might help.
By the way, you need `client.get_authorize_url(request_token)` to get an authorization URL after obtaining `request_token`. Access this URL from the browser, and the `oauth_verifier` will appear in the parameters of the callback URL if successfully authorized.